# Monotone Boolean Function

Tags: c++

I need a help . I want  to write the function that will check wheter  boolean function is monotone or no.
For example if we have function f(x1, x2) of 2 arguments

1. f(0, 0) = 0
2. f(0, 1) = 0
3. f(1, 0) = 0
4. f(1, 1) = 1

for this function  will return true.

Comment: "monotonic function" is a mathematical term, it can not be applied to C++ functions. There is nothing preventing that function from returning different results with same arguments like  `f(1, 1) = 1` `f(1, 1) = 0` `f(1, 1) = 0` `f(1, 1) = 1`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is *not* a free code-writing service.

Comment: you are mixing the mathematical notion of function with the programming notion of function. I don't understand what you mean. You need to first clarify your question, and then ask for a specific question. "I need help" and then just dumping an exercise requirements is off-topic here.

Comment: Function f : {0, 1} n → {0, 1} is monotone, if f (α1, . . . , αn) ≤
f (β1, . . . , βn) whenever (α1, . . . , αn) ≺+ (β1, . . . , βn). It is Boolean Algebra

Answer (score 0):

In the general sense you cannot. Imagine a c++ function like this:

```
bool f(bool x1, bool x2) {
    return rand() > 50;
}
```

Regardless of the check you implement you cannot for sure say this function will be a monotone or not. You may receive your expected result above sometimes, then sometimes you will not ...

Comment: `return rand() > 0.5;` seems a little silly since `rand()` returns `int` but you are comparing with a `double`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Changed, but that's not really the point of the answer.